# multi instance failover clustering (sql server)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, sql-server, windows-server-2012

just want to straighten my concept properly - when we are talking about SQL multi instance failover cluster,  e.g. on a 2 node cluster, it means that each node can run its own sql instance, but each instances are running its own database right ?

> e.g. 2 nodes (node1, node2)
>   sql instance A on node1
>   sql instance B on node2

sql instance A and B are individual instances and are not sharing the same database right ?

when node1 is down, SQL instance A will move to node2 but both sql instance A and B are still separate databases - right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. A traditional failover cluster may contain multiple instances, and each instance may contain multiple databases. A database is part of only one instance, and an instance only runs on one node at a time.

Comment: so it isn't like oracle rac whereby 2 instance share the same database yea ? in ms sql, the database is only use by 1 instance. so the instances on each node are running their own separate databases yea ?

Comment: Right. The cluster fails over the whole instance and all the associated databases. To get something closer to RAC, you'd use an AlwaysOn availability group.

Comment: so at any moment, only 1 particular instance/database run on 1 particular node, another node might run another instance, but it is a separate instance with its own database - right ? (sorry I know I sounds naggy, just wanna be sure)

Comment: Correct -- a node could run more than one instance at a time if it has sufficient resources, but any given instance is only active on one node at a time, and a single database is an active member of only one instance. (Now, you might be able to set up two instances such that instance A has a db active and mirrors or replicates that to instance B, but that would be generally overly complicated.)

Comment: just curious - why can't ms sql do active-active ?

Comment: It can, when you use AlwaysOn instead of traditional failover clusters.

Comment: but alwayson seems to be like dataguard in oracle. (more like a mirrored database in comparison to having 2 nodes actively sharing 1 database)